# Firebase custom claims returns Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, claims-authentication

I am trying to read the user's custom claims and I would like to return the values of the claims to the client individually.

This code has worked for months. However, all of a sudden it returns the error "Object is possibly undefined".

This code appears on the following lines:

```
role: userRecord.customClaims["role"],
type: userRecord.customClaims["type"],
```

Here is the entire code snippet:

```
exports.checkAuthClaim = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const userId = data.userId;
  return admin
      .auth()
      .getUser(userId)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        console.log(userRecord.customClaims);
        return {
          role: userRecord.customClaims["role"],
          type: userRecord.customClaims["type"],
        };
      });
});
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @devOP1 ,  just want to confirm, if this question is related to your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794009/get-data-from-firestore-document-and-use-in-cloud-function). It seems that you have the same error but you haven't found yet what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the user maybe undefined, this could happen if you use invalid userId. Use optional chaining to get rid of this error.

```
        return {
          role: userRecord?.customClaims?.["role"],
          type: userRecord?.customClaims?.["type"],
        };
```

simply check for the undefined

Comment: after adding the question marks, it still says the object is undefined

Comment: `userRecord?.customClaims?.["role"]` simply continue the optional chaining

Answer (score 0):

It means your claims must be `null` in that case.

you need to explicitly set the `claim` then you can access it

```
  initializeApp({ projectId: 'enter-project-id' })
  const uid = 'user-id';
  auth.getAuth()
    .getUser(uid)
    .then((userRecord) => {
      auth.getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{...userRecord.customClaims, superadmin: true}).then(() => {
        console.log('[setCustomUserClaims] set successfully')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting user:', error);
    });
```